# What is the best way to extend Store Group model?

Tags: model, extension-attributes

I would like to modify **Store Group model** to add a few more columns needed by my business logic.

Magento 2 document only writes about extending models by EAV but I find that Store Group model does not support EAV.

Technically, It's possible to modify `store_group` table during module's `Setup/InstallSchema`.  But is it ok, by principles, to do so?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create Simple module and create UpgradeSchema.php file to add extra column to store_group table.

**app/code/Vendorname/Packagename/Setup/UpgradeSchema.php file,**

```
<?php
namespace Vendorname\Packagename\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;

        $installer->startSetup();
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1') < 0) {
            $installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
                $installer->getTable('store_group'),
                'store_extra1',
                [
                    'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    'nullable' => true,
                    'comment' => 'Store group extra 1'
                ]
            );

            $installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
                $installer->getTable('store_group'),
                'store_extra2',
                [
                    'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    'nullable' => true,
                    'comment' => 'Store group extra 2'
                ]
            );
        }

        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

**In app/code/Vendorname/Packagename/etc/module.xml file,**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendorname_Packagename" setup_version="1.0.1">        
    </module>
</config>
```

run upgrade command,

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Comment: Thanks for example. Is this the official way to do so? In fact, I've discussed with team and we are not sure if this is a good practice because it might affect Magento upgrading.

Comment: Yes, This is the official way to upgrade table.

Comment: You can check it from core module example,  vendor/magento/module-catalog/Setup/UpgradeSchema.php Also There are some other module also do same type of upgrade script in core.